# Generating XSL from a XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml file like this :

```
<catalog>
 <Letter xmlns:xsi="http://www.irica.com/ECEP/1383-12/SendSchema-instance"     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:ECEP_Letter.xsd">
 <Protocol Name="ECEP" Version="1.01" /> 
 <Software SoftwareDeveloper="My software company" Version="1.0" GUID="{9A0C9627-1052-4F88-8084-77CE777E7126}" /> 
 <Sender Organization="عنوان سازمان فرستنده" Department="واحد مديريت؛؛مدير کل" Position="مدير کل" Name="مهندس مدیری" Code="985120" /> 
 <Receiver Organization="عنوان سازمان گیرنده" Department="معاونت مالی؛؛معاون" Position="معاون" Name="مهندس مالی" Code="359234" ReceiveType="Origin" /> 
  ...
  </Letter>
  </catalog>
```

I have written an xls theme but the problem is I can't see as an instance `SoftwareDeveloper` or `Version`. How can I solve this?

Edited:

Here's some part of my code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
  <body>
 <table border="1">
 <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
 <th>Title</th>
 <th>Artist</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="catalog/Letter/Software/SoftwareDeveloper"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="catalog/Letter/Software/Version"/></td>

  </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you please show the xslt you have written please? Also, it may help if you showed your expected output in this case. Thank you!

Comment: What is the "cd" for in *catalog/cd/Software/SoftwareDeveloper* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your paths are not right, you want

```
<xsl:value-of select="catalog/Letter/Software/@SoftwareDeveloper"/>
```

and similar changes to the other paths.